# Init database before tests JUnit5 and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit

My project is using Spring, Hibernate ant JUnit 5. What is the best approach to init DB before all test?

Here is how I tired to do it:

```
class DbCreatorService {
   @Autowired
   private Service1;
   @Autowired
   private Service2;
....
}

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml")
@Transactional
class MyTest {

    @BeforeAll
    static void initDatabase(@Autowired DbCreatorService dbCreatorService ) {
        dbCreatorService.initDB()
    }
}
```

When I call `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` somewhere in the `initDB()` I get: `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread`. `sessionFactory` is injected with @Autowired.

Comment: What does the initDB() method do? Does it initialize connection to the DB or does it prepare the tables with data before the tests?

Comment: it creates the database and inserts data  in the tables

Comment: I updated my question with more details

Comment: I have been doing it with embedded H2, on test scope. I have some code from work to show you. I will try to write an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My tests just read from the DB and I wanted to init DB only once before all tests. My final solution:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml")
@Transactional
class MyTest {
    @Autowired 
    private DbCreatorService dbCreatorService;

    @BeforeAll
    void initDatabase() {
        dbCreatorService.initDB()
    }
}
```

Comment: How does that work when the method marked as `@BeforeAll` has to be static?

Comment: It works because of @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS) https://www.baeldung.com/java-beforeall-afterall-non-static

Answer (score 2):

### What we are trying to achieve?

A database scenario that is test friendly, and can be setup easily before and after each test case.

### How I achieved it

I have been using embedded H2 database on test scope, with a database setup via SQL script before each test case.

1. First, add the H2 on test scope dependency on pom.xml (you are using Maven right?).

   `<dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>`
2. Then, setup your JUnit tests class.

SampleTestClass.java

```
@SpringBootTest // Allows you to autowire beans on your test class

@AutoConfigureTestDatabase // Configures a database on test scope instead of your regular database config.

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) // Runs test context with SpringRunner.class

@SqlGroup({ // Setups .sql files to be run on specific triggers. In this case, before each test method the script will be ran.
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:beforeTest.sql"),
})

@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD) // The spring application context will be considered "dirty" before each test method, and will be rebuilt. It means that
// your autowired beans will not carry any data between test cases.

public class SampleTestClass {

// write your test cases here...
}
```

3. On your test classpath, add a [beforeTest.sql](https://pastebin.com/RuZnFyEd) file that will be ran before each test method. That file may include the table creation, and some data insert for you to work with. If you need some additional database interaction, you can always have a method annotated with `@Before` on your test class. That method will be ran before each test case.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation, but I needed a way to init DB before all test methods not for each test method. Also I am using JUnit5 and just Spring not SpringBoot

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your requisites. Still, I believe you can still use some of those techniques to setup your DB for tests. If you need to init DB before ALL tests, like you said, JUnit @Before annotation is your best bet. The only difference there between Spring and Spring boot are the context config annotations, and I believe you already got those sorted out on your code.

Comment: I use @Before with a flag, so I init the DB only once, but this looks like a hack.

Comment: Using before for general setups on a test suite is the most elegant sollution.

Comment: Was this setup helpful? Did you find a more ellegant sollution?

Comment: I added an answer with my final solution